# How to install and update a wordpress plugin from a single location to many accounts?

Tags: wordpress

I have the following:
    •   an FTP server with CPanel running on top of WHMCS
    •   three MySQL databases, linked to different users
    •   three WordPress accounts linked to the different databases
How to install a plugin separately, and link its installation to the three WordPress accounts? I want to do this because I will have  a large scale proJect ahead, and i **need to update the plugin from a single location**, which I want to link the many accounts, in order to make it easy, from an architectural point of sight, to update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your direct question :

[Jetpack](https://jetpack.me/support/site-management/) can do it . ( free & official )

[infinitewp](http://infinitewp.com/) can do it. ( free )

[managewp](https://managewp.com/) can do it .

[wpremote](https://wpremote.com/) can do it .

And I am sure that if you will [google](https://www.google.co.il/search?oq=control%20multiple%20wordpress%20installs%20&sugexp=chrome,mod=2&%7Bgoogle:instantFieldTrialGroupParameter%7Dsourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=control%20multiple%20wordpress%20installs%20&gws_rd=ssl) a bit you will find more ...
I only used infinitewp in the past (self hosted and maintained ) and it was quite efficient.

For your situation : you can also consider activating [wordpress in network state](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network), but [read this before](https://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network)

EDIT I :

After Comments :

Even if your setup seems a bit illogical, yes, you can move the wp-content , or the plugins directory within , by editing each one ( of the million ) of the `wp-config` files for the accounts you have ..

[CLICK HERE...](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_plugin_folder)

Set `WP_CONTENT_DIR` to the full local path of this directory (no trailing slash), e.g.

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-content' );
```

Set `WP_CONTENT_URL` to the full URI of this directory (no trailing slash), e.g.

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example/blog/wp-content');
```

Set `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` to the full local path of this directory (no trailing slash), e.g.

```
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-content/plugins' );
```

Set `WP_PLUGIN_URL` to the full URI of this directory (no trailing slash), e.g.

```
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL', 'http://example/blog/wp-content/plugins');
```

If you have compability issues with plugins Set `PLUGINDIR` to the full local path of this directory (no trailing slash), e.g.

```
define( 'PLUGINDIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-content/plugins' );
```

Mind you, some plugins, depending on functionality and coding quality might fail to word correctly ..

Comment: thank you for your reply, and taking the time to answer my question. It's very kind of you. I know about infinitewp, and network state. I am Just wondering if with a package like Jetpack, i can have a single installation of the plugin, aside in an ftp server, or a separate wordpress account, and the different wordpress installations will use this installation as their own. the reason for the is to prevent a lot of traffic on the servers, by instantiating massive amounts of threads. with votes of a wonderful autumn. tiago

Comment: Not really sure what you mean with a lot of traffic...just by updating plugins ? and as for jetpack - just try it . I never did myself.

Comment: if you have to update a plugin which is installed on one million accounts. and the plugin is 4Mb. then you will be generating at least 4 terabytes of data in terms of server traffic. in terms of systems architecture, i think it's something to bear in mind, when programming a software piece, or developing concepts in terms of system architecture. kind regards

Comment: If you have a justified  million account , the 4Mb per account every now and then ( plugin updates are hardly daily - not even monthly  ) should not matter ... But if this is really your real case scenario - where ALL million accounts use the same exact plugins -  than you will have to use the network, or wait for another answer ..

Comment: thanks for taking the time to think about a solution. :) I really appreciate it. I will try to see wether or not someone else can provide a more appropriate insight on the topic. i suggest you to leave your answer there, once that might perfectly turn to be useful for another users. kind regards

Comment: ahhh i think your edit to my post may perfectly solve the problem. i will look deeper into it and try to figure out wether or not this is the case

Comment: If it is so , than please upvote and / or accept the answer as to mark the question resolved . ( the little `v`and arrows near the answer )

Comment: Just one more question. does copy the file. or moves it. because if it deletes the original file, we may have to look into another attribute. anyway this is really close to what i am looking at

Comment: i would like to upvote it, but i don't have privileges for that yet (i need to have at least 15 reputation)

Comment: I really have no idea what you mean..you have to edit the `wp-config` to edit the constant on every install.. if you have another issue , please ask it in a seperate question, or edit the original one .and about the upvoting , ok, but you can accept it if you will click the little "V"..